# Android Studio is giving me errors when I start it

Tags: java, android

Whenever I start Android Studio, I get the following error message

> Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher

Comment: Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program.

Comment: how do I check? I mean my system is windows7 32bit.  The error is about what ?,Is it android studio version problem ?  I didnt get the single clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by figuring out whether your computer is 32 or 64 bit. If you don't know how, see the start of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/949577/623128) (up until the `about` menu)

There you will see if your system is x64 or x32 bit. From there install the correct version of Android studio.

Open the directory where you have installed Android Studio.

- `<android-studio-install-dir>`\bin\studio.exe is the 32-bit launcher.
- `<android-studio-install-dir>`\bin\studio64.exe is the 64-bit launcher.

Select the one that matches your system and launch it. Remove any shortcuts leading to the wrong executable and replace them with the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but I have resolved it the next:

1) Install jdk1.8 or higher

2) In AndroidStudio File->Project Structure->SDK Location, select your directory where the JKD is located, by default Studio uses embedded JDK but for some reason it produces error=216.

3) Click Ok.

Comment: in the SDK location? choose the JDK directory? but it says sdk does not contain any platforms

Answer (score 1):

The studio android 2.2 is setting the time of installation the path of the JDK to the JRE folder. Enter android studio setting and add the correct path for the JDK. Only that.